# In SQL Server using PowerShell to get folder size I get a "missing property name after reference operator" error

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

This is my code using SSMS:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE

CREATE TABLE #tfoldsizeinMB(size float)

declare @cmd varchar(100)='powershell "(Get-ChildItem \\Share01\report\0000 -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum).sum"'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

This is the output:

> Missing property name after reference operator.
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingPropertyName

This works in Powershell, but not in SSMS.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are defining cmd as varchar(100) but the length of your cmd is 102. Increase the size and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  THank you @Jawad!